# Why pgx returns connection busy on commit?

Tags: go, pgx

I have a function to insert values to the table in bulk. `tx.Commit()` returns `conn busy`. As I got from reading code is that `conn.Begin()` actually makes it busy.

So the question is how to do this correctly? Should I use transactions together with batch queries at all? Or transaction is created under the hood?

```golang
// InsertItems adds items to the table
func (r *Repository) InsertItems(ctx context.Context, values []service.Transaction) error {

    conn, err := r.pool.Acquire(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("acquire connection: %w", err)
    }
    defer conn.Release()

    tx, err := conn.Begin(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("starting pgx transaction: %w", err)
    }
    defer func() { _ = tx.Rollback(ctx) }()

    batch := pgx.Batch{}

    for _, v := range values {

        query := fmt.Sprintf(`INSERT INTO %v (id, date, amount) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`, r.tableName)

        batch.Queue(query, v.ID, v.Date, v.Amount)
    }

    batchRes := tx.SendBatch(ctx, &batch)
    defer func() {
        if err := batchRes.Close(); err != nil {
            logger.Errorf("closing batch result: %v", err)
        }
    }()

    cmdTag, err := batchRes.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("batch res exec: %w", err)
    }

    logger.Debugf("inserted rows: %d", cmdTag.RowsAffected())

    if err := tx.Commit(ctx); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("commiting pgx transaction: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: Works! Please post is as a separate comment so I will check it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling commit before calling close on the batch result. You need to first close the batch result **before** you can use the underlying connection again.

To enforce the correct order of the deferred operations you could do something like the following:

```golang
// InsertItems adds items to the table
func (r *Repository) InsertItems(ctx context.Context, values []service.Transaction) (err error) {
    conn, err := r.pool.Acquire(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("acquire connection: %w", err)
    }
    defer conn.Release()

    batch := new(pgx.Batch)
    for _, v := range values {
        query := fmt.Sprintf(`INSERT INTO %v (id, date, amount) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)`, r.tableName)
        _ = batch.Queue(query, v.ID, v.Date, v.Amount)
    }

    tx, err := conn.Begin(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("starting pgx transaction: %w", err)
    }   
    result := tx.SendBatch(ctx, batch)
    defer func() {
        if e := result.Close(); e != nil {
            logger.Errorf("closing batch result: %v", e)
            err = e
        }
        
        if err != nil {
            _ = tx.Rollback(ctx)
        } else {
            if e := tx.Commit(ctx); e != nil {
                err = e
            }
        }
    }()
    tag, err := result.Exec()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("batch res exec: %w", err)
    }
    
    logger.Debugf("inserted rows: %d", tag.RowsAffected())
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Interesting thing: in case of a bad insert query (i.e. constraint violation) result.Close() returns an error and Rollback() returns conn busy again. But only if batch contains only one request